# ‘He decided’ vs. ‘He had decided’

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past, perfect-aspect

> *He decided that I could have the apartment before he looked at my credit report*.

I found that sentence in an exercise, and I wonder why it isn't:

> *He **had** decided that I could have the apartment before he looked at my credit report*.

because the past perfect simple is used to describe one action that happened before another action in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Had could indicate that it is now no longer true.

Whereas

> He decided that I could have the apartment before he looked at my credit report.

indicates that it is still this way now

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. There are many circumstances in which either the pluperfect or the simple past are interchangeable (this being one of them), and it can depend on whether you want to emphasise that one event preceded the other or not. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the first example, and the meaning is perfectly clear. However if you wanted to emphasise the earlier decision, or his mind had been changed in the interim (He had decided....before...but has now changed his mind.) then the pluperfect is the route to go.

Comment: To expand a bit, the person in the first sentence still got the apartment (they lucked out), whereas the implication of the second sentence is that he changed his mind.

Answer (score 0):

If we use "after" or "before" in our sentence which totally indicates what action is about the past, useing the past perfect is not necessary and we can use the simple past instead.

Ex:
I arrived after he left the house.
Or
I arrived after he had left the house.

Both are correct.

Comment: I agree, but can you find a **supporting reference** that refutes the 'past perfect must always be used in a sentence for an event happening prior to one for which the past simple is used in that sentence' rule some seem to have picked up?